# On sums involving Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

I've been struggling with the following claim without being able to prove it, so your help would be highly appreciated:

Let $\varphi(n)$ be Euler's totient function. Show that there is a constant $0<K$ such that for any natural number $N$, $KN\leq\frac{\varphi(1)}{1}+\frac{\varphi(2)}{2}+...+\frac{\varphi(N)}{N}$.

Comment: $$\varphi(N)>\frac{N}{e^{\gamma} \cdot \ln (\ln N)+\frac{3}{ \ln (\ln N)}}$$ , for $N>2$

Comment: @pedja: What is $\gamma$, and how did you get this inequality?

Comment: That's the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_of_the_function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\varphi(k)}{k} \ge \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{\varphi(k)}{k}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[\frac{n}{k}\right]\varphi(k) = \frac{n+1}{2} $$

Thus you can choose $K = \frac{1}{2}$.

The last step uses the identity:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[\frac{n}{k}\right]\varphi(k) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

and the first inequality uses $\left[\frac{n}{k}\right] \le \frac{n}{k}$, where $[x]$ gives the integer part of $x$.

Multiple proofs of the last identity can be found here: [Identity involving Euler's totient function: $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor \varphi(k) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8002/identity-involving-eulers-totient-function-sum-limits-k-1n-left-lfloor)