# Prove $\sum_{d \leq x} \mu(d)\left\lfloor \frac xd \right\rfloor = 1 $

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function

I am trying to show $$\sum_{d \leq x} \mu(d)\left\lfloor \frac{x}{d} \right\rfloor = 1 \;\;\;\; \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}, \; x \geq 1 $$ I know that the sum over the divisors $d$ of $n$ is zero if $n \neq 1$. So we can rule out integers that are divisors of $x$ (if $x > 1$). I am not sure if I am on the right track to prove this. Any hints would be helpful. This is homework.

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8002

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is typical example in Möbius Inversion.

Use $\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)=\epsilon(n)$ where $\epsilon(n)=1$ if $n=1$, and 0 otherwise.
Now,
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)=\sum_{n\leq x}\epsilon(n)=1$$
Changing the order of summation, we get
$$\sum_{d\leq x}\mu(d)\sum_{d|n, n\leq x}1=1$$
Then the inside summation is $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\right\rfloor$.
So, we are done.

Comment: Could you explain how you get that from changing the order

Comment: The change of order works as follows: First, sum over $n$ inside instead of $d$. Then inside sum is over all multiples of $d$ but $\leq x$. That number is precisely $\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\rfloor$.

Comment: Is it possible to deduce $\left| \sum_{d\leq x} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \right| \leq 1$

Comment: Use $\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\rfloor=\frac{x}{d}+\{\frac{x}{d}\}$ where $\{\frac{x}{d}\}$ is the fractional part of $\frac{x}{d}$

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by fractional part. so [6/4] = 1 + 1/2?

Comment: @TylerHilton see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657156/prove-left-vert-sum-n-1n-frac-munn-right-vert-leqslant-1-where/2699866#2699866

Answer (score 5):

It appears indeed to be an instance of the [Moebius inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations), applied to $f(x)  = \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $g(x)  = 1$. We have
$$
f(x)=\sum_{d \in \mathbf{Z}, 1 \le d \le x} g(x/d). 
$$
Then
$$
g(x) = \sum_{d \in \mathbf{Z}, 1 \le d \le x} \mu(d) f(x/d)
$$

Comment: From both answers, I am confused on how the floor function is equivalent to the summation of the divisors