# An application of Mobius Inversion $\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(\frac{n}{d})\nu(d) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function

Show that $\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(\frac{n}{d})\nu(d) = 1$, for any positive integer n. Where $\mu$ denotes the Mobius function defined by $\mu(n)=(-1)^{s}$ if $n=p_{1} \dotsc p_{s}$ for distinct primes $p_{1} \dotsc p_{s}$ and $\mu(n)=0$ otherwise, and $\nu(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$.

I think I have to apply the Mobius Inversion Theorem somehow or use properties of the Dirichlet product, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove it's true for primes? prime powers? Can you prove it's a multiplicative function?

Comment: OK I have managed to prove all three things and after a bit of work the result should follow?

Comment: Well, that's the point of multiplicative functions – once you can evaluate them at prime powers, you can evaluate them everywhere.

Comment: One formula for $\nu$ is $\nu(n) = \sum_{d|n} 1$.  What does Mobius inversion do to that?

Comment: Compare also with the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332588/prove-sum-d-leq-x-mud-left-lfloor-frac-xd-right-rfloor-1?rq=1).

Comment: This is simply $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\times \zeta(s)^2 = \zeta(s).$$

Answer (score 2):

$\nu(n)= \sum_{d|n} 1$ => According to the [Moebius Inversion Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) $\sum_{d|n} μ(n/d)\nu(d) = 1$